# Save content between delimeters and compare

Tags: bash, shell, comparison

I have many difficulties to extract the content delimeted between `'[ ]'` and compare it using shell script. After that i need to erase the other fields with `[]`.

I received files which filenames content som `[xxxx]` pattern, one of them useful and which i use to classify them.

One example:

```
Input: sample[t.225][lb.445][21042013][0913605].extension
Output (pattern lb.445): sample[lb.445].extension
```

I know i can use a grep with the pattern but after that i don't know how to erase the other fields in the filename. I think the strategy of use a grep is not the best option and the option of use a loop sound really weird in shell script and pattern comparison.

Comment: your "pattern" is everytime the second [...] as in the sample?

Comment: No, the pattern sometimes is in third or other position.

Comment: so, how to identify the pattern? it is begins with lb? or? Please try describe fully the matching needs ;)

Answer (score 1):

awk may help in this case:

```
awk -F'[][]' '{print $1"["$4"]"$NF}' input
```

the above line takes the text from the 2nd `[...]` block

take the example in your question:

```
kent$  echo "sample[t.225][lb.445][21042013][0913605].extension"|awk -F'[][]' '{print $1"["$4"]"$NF}'                                                                       
sample[lb.445].extension
```

Comment: But the pattern is not always in the second position.

Comment: so you mean the part you need could be any where, but the text must be `lb.445`? what is the criteria to extract?

Comment: The criteria is lb.xxx into [ ]